# as.POSIXct does not get format correctly

Tags: r

I want to get hour 17 of the certain weekday (Sunday for example) of the week. So my try is

```
as.POSIXct(format(Sys.time(), '%U Sunday 17'), format = '%U %A %H')
```

which gives `2016-03-18 17:00:00` (Friday). It must be something trivial that I miss.

**Update.** This question is about a function producing unexpected result rather than about calculation method. So to my mind it is not a duplicate. And the trivial thing that I missed was year specification in format. So the correct answer is `as.POSIXct(format(Sys.time(), '%Y %U Sunday 17'), format = '%Y %U %A %H')`.

Comment: Most likely `as.POSIXct(paste(Sys.Date() - as.numeric(format(Sys.time(), "%u")), "17:00:00"))`

Comment: @danas.zuokas I've posted the answer for your specific purpose in the directed original post